# How to use the free form in mathematica 10 to give me as input the tempratures in a specific place?

Tags: free-form-input

How to use the free-form in mathematica to give me the tempratures in a specific place in the world from specific timeline?

What should write in the command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use free-form input in a calculation, you can use [`Interpreter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpreter.html)

```
AirTemperatureData@{{Interpreter["Location"]["Grand Canyon"],
    Interpreter["Date"]["jan 7, 1999"]}}
(* {Quantity[Interval[{17.6, 55.4}], "DegreesFahrenheit"]} *)
```

Note that Celsius units would have been returned if I weren't in the US.  To get a more specific answer, use "DateTime" instead of "Date":

```
AirTemperatureData@{{Interpreter["Location"]["grand canyon"],
    Interpreter["DateTime"]["8am jan 7, 1999"]}}
(* {Quantity[19.4, "DegreesFahrenheit"]} *)
```

You can also use [`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) to get the information, but it's a bit trickier to get it in a computable format

```
WolframAlpha["grand canyon weather jan 7, 1999", "Result"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I've been meaning to learn how to get data like this...+1.

Answer (score 3):

First I type `ctrl+enter`, and then I enter in "temperature in Rio Brazil from june 1, 2014 to june 30, 2014" gives me

```
AirTemperatureData[
  Entity["City", {"RioDeJaneiro", "RioDeJaneiro", 
   "Brazil"}], {DateObject[{2014, 6, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 6, 30}]}]
```

which I believe is exactly what you're looking for.

Of course I would recommend learning to do this programmatically.

Comment: How can I use mathematica to show me only the month of february from 2000 to 2016 of a specific place?